# Does cloth baking take a (steadily increasing) number of frame samples into account? Can I control the count?

Tags: physics, baking, cloth-simulation

So, when I'm baking a cloth simulation, I generally only need so much precision in the beginning. I'm still lining up my model and getting everything in place; until I know that it is what it's meant to be, I stick to simplistics.

Workspace renderer. Minimum modifiers. 640x480 (or even QVGA at 320x240). I do the animation before the major sculpting, and then add on to it, a little at a time.

The problem I'm seeing comes into play when my character is wearing something with a cloth modifier. Baking it can help later, but it seems as though with every passing frame, I have to wait a little longer. As an artist who is also a programmer, it occurs to me that this might be because, instead of mapping velocity persistently for each point on the mesh, it might be looking over the time curve of every point on the cloth mesh up to that frame. So, frame two might only need one frame to determine its velocity; but frame 249 might have 248 frames to look over and combine with some kind of Poisson distribution most likely.

This is a good thing, but I can't prove it—I have no idea where in the source code to look. However, if it is true, is it possible to set a maximum number of frames to look back through when baking cloth? Can I limit it to, say, thirty two frames?